# Count number of rows between start and end date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with few hundred thousand rows, with columns containing a start and finish datetime, something like this:

```
ID    StartDateTime              FinishDateTime
--------------------------------------------------------
1     2001-01-01 04:05:06.789    2001-02-03 04:05:06.789
2     2001-01-01 05:05:06.789    2001-01-01 07:05:06.789
3     2001-01-01 06:05:06.789    2001-02-04 07:05:06.789
4     2001-03-01 06:05:06.789    2001-02-03 04:05:06.789
```

For each row, I need to count the number of 'active' rows at the start time; as in count rows that start before and finish after the startdatetime for each row. For instance: for ID=3, the startdatetime falls between the startdatetime and finishdatetime of ID=1 and ID=2, but not ID=3 or ID=4, so it should return 2.

The desired output is:

```
ID    ActiveRows
-----------------
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     0
```

I can get it to work using the query below, but it takes hours to run.

```
select
    ID,
    (select count(1) 
     from table tbl2 
     where tbl2.StartDateTime < tbl.StartDateTime 
       and tbl2.FinishDateTime > tbl.StartDateTime) as 'ActiveRows'
from 
    table tbl
```

I've also tried joining the table on itself, but it also seems extremely slow.

```
select
    tbl.ID, count(1)
from 
    table tbl
left join table 
    tbl2 on tbl2.StartDateTime < tbl.StartDateTime 
         and tbl2.FinishDateTime > tbl.StartDateTime
group by 
    tbl.ID
```

What is the fastest way to perform this calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `Apply` operator

```
SELECT tbl.id, 
       oa.activerows 
FROM   yourtable tbl 
       OUTER apply(SELECT Count(tbl2.id) 
                   FROM   yourtable tbl2 
                   WHERE  tbl2.startdatetime < tbl.startdatetime 
                          AND tbl2.finishdatetime > tbl.startdatetime) oa (activerows)
```

and your original query should be using `LEFT JOIN` to get the `ID's` with `0` count

To further improve the performance you can create a `non clustered` index on yourtable

```
Create Nonclustered Index Nix_table on 
      yourtable (startdatetime,finishdatetime) Include (Id)
```

- ### [Live Demo](http://rextester.com/RQMIM95981)

Comment: Thanks @prdp. Certainly a huge amount faster: 14:15 for 242,180 rows with the non-clustered index created. Still would love to know if there's an even faster way!

Comment: @Tim AFAIK, these are the three possible ways to your requirement. May be add bounty to your question to get more attention. Someone may come up with better approach